# How do I pass column names from DefaultTableModel into Jasper report?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am creating a PDF generator which should bring in the column names from the `colNames` passed into the `TableModel model`. The data is coming through OK, but the headers are just reading as COLUMN_1 and COLUMN_2.

I have tried Googling the problem but there is precious little information out there about the interaction between java and jasper reports.

If I change `<text><![CDATA[COLUMN_1]]></text>` to `<text><![CDATA[FOO]]></text>` then the column name is FOO, which suggests that the jrxml is treating this as plain text rather than a field. If I change it to `<![CDATA[$F{COLUMN_4}]]>` then the column header is just $F.

#### Java

```
    private Vector<String> getMockColumnNames() {
        Vector<String> colNames = new Vector<>();
   
        colNames.add("Name");
        colNames.add("Age");
        return colNames;
    }

    private Vector<Vector<String>> getMockData(){
       Vector<Vector<String>> rows = new Vector<>();
        rows.add(new Vector<>(Arrays.asList("Chris", "33")));
        rows.add(new Vector<>(Arrays.asList("Steve", "44")));
        return rows;
    }


    public byte[] generate(CompositeView data) throws IOException {
            try {
                final JasperReport report = reportsFileStore.getJasperReport(foo.xml);

                Vector<Vector<String>> allData = getMockData();
                Vector<String> colNames = getMockColumnNames();

           TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(allData, colNames);
                JRTableModelDataSource dataSource = new JRTableModelDataSource(model);

                // Create an empty datasource.
                JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, new HashMap<>(), dataSource);

                byte[] bytes = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
                return bytes;
    }
```

#### foo.JRXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 5.0.1  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_2" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="NoDataSection" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="ca6b24de-ed82-4dcf-84c4-84dd89553a90">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="CN LC"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="COLUMN_0" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="COLUMN_1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="30" uuid="7bcc962f-26d0-4ff2-889d-c477f2748419"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Table Model Report..."]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="18">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="81" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="620dad59-995a-46a2-95a3-92eddda468ad"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true" size="14"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[$F{COLUMN_0}]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" mode="Transparent" x="81" y="0" width="81" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="1de494cd-8da7-435d-8d70-81664ebf15c9"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true" size="14"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[$F{COLUMN_1}]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="12" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="81" height="12" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="7b7e0871-657c-4956-8227-08b0e4cf6de8"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{COLUMN_0}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" mode="Transparent" x="81" y="0" width="81" height="12" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="7d7aa39e-5564-462e-afdd-e629cc557aa0"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{COLUMN_1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: please share the exported pdf file

Comment: @Rathnayake https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bNjmquP2bxzA_m3hX5RvyihBlsjR2txm/view?usp=sharing

I have made some edits to the code, as the code that I shared was an attempt to provide a simplified example of the real problem, but my example did not work in practice.